# Values are kept without value tag inside input

Tags: php, redirect, post

I have been creating a form for an advert and I have a slight issue with this.

When user enters all his information and press submit (if everything ok) he will be redirected to other page to confirm email address etc, but if I click on that page to go back to the page I previously was (just using chromes back button), I can see all values inside the input field even input html code has no value tag (see image below):

[image]

I tryed to use sessions to prevent that, but I have same problem. And by coming back,user can submit form again and again..Any suggestions how to prevent this problem?

Comment: use form reset after form submission and validate form before submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have jQuery enabled in your site, you could listen for BFCACHE events, which is the technology keeping the values cached.

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
  var form = $('formid'); 
  form[0].reset();
});
```

The above is an example of how content can be cleared.

Adding the `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store` header should disable saving without javascript.

Comment: Yeah this kind of worked for me. All I had to do is insert 

`$("#myform")[0].reset();`

to my jquery code and it clears all form input after submition

Comment: Well it does work, but If I disable javascript in the browser, I have same problem anyway :)

Comment: Added a potential nonjs fix